# snipMate filetype isn't set correctly

Tags: vim, go, snipmate

I downloaded vim and used it in a python file and the snippets worked perfectly. But when I tried to use snipMate in a .go file (golang) it didn't work. I read the documentation and couldn't find an answer but when I manually used the command ":set ft=go"
the snippets worked. Why does snipMate automatically work for python and not go. Snippet files for both languages are supplied. How do I get snippets for go to automatically work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your .go files aren't getting set to the appropriate filetype. You can use

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go setl ft=go
```

in your ~/.vimrc to remedy this.

The appropriate place for files like this is in your `~/.vim/ftdetect` directory. For instance, you could create a file called `~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim` and put the command in there.

Comment: Almost. the place is `~/.vim/ftdetect/` The stuff in `ftplugin` is sourced after the filetype has been detected, and contains filetype-specific settings.

Comment: Oops, I misspoke. Thanks for the catch, @IngoKarkat